# Google storage transfer job (From Amazon s3 bucket) fails with error Unauthorized

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I had created a google storage transfer job which has the following configuration

[image]

Source S3 bucket has the following policy,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::jaya/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::jaya"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The transfer job kicks but failed for an unknown reason, the reason I got from the transfer job is,

```
Object: s3_fetch:0001_part_00.gz
Details: Http error code: Unauthorized.
```

The funniest thing is, source bucket has the file `0001_part_00.gz` which means transfer job can able to fetch the file name from s3 bucket but it couldn't able to download from s3. What could be the reason?

Comment: Enable logging on the bucket, so you can see what requests are being made.  How large is the `0001_part_00.gz` object?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  `0001_part_00.gz` object size is 100 KB, I don't find any relevant log

Comment: There isn't anything in your [bucket log](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html)?  It's strange that the error is `Unauthorized` (401), because [S3 uses different error responses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html), most often `Forbidden` (403) and `Bad Request` (400), with no documented cases of returning `Unauthorized`.  That suggests (but does not prove) that the error is not originating from S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue all day today but now it's working.

I tried creating a bucket from within the job creation process and it worked. I then recreated one of my previously failing jobs (to a bucket created outside the transfer job) and it's also working.

So maybe something was broken at AWS or GCP today.